# Spark: Filter task not serializable due to previous cluster algorithm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have clustered some data and I have created an RDD that contains the id of the elements and the according cluster by zipping the `id_rdd` which contained the ids of the elements and the `cluster_rdd` which contained the appropriate cluster number for each id.

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
```

I received a new datapoint and predicted the cluster this datapoint is located into:

```
val location = model.predict(vector)

location: Int = 1
```

Now I want to get all the elements of `rdd` that belong to the same cluster as vector. I thought I could use filter for this:

```
val output = rdd.filter(_._2 == s"$location")
```

However I get the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:340)
.....
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:    org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
```

How do I avoid this? I tried variations of that command but for some reason it always tries to serialize the previously used (and finished) clustering algorithm. I tried caching `rdd` before running the filter but I get the same error. Why does the interpreter pick that up? Could this be due to spark's lazy evaluation and it is just now calculating the proper cluster values for the `rdd`? Short of using collect (which I'd rather avoid if possible) or hopping between RDDs and Dataframes, is there any other way I can solve this?

Comment: Looks like you are using a non-serialized class inside filter function, in Spark all the transformations are running on multiple nodes, it means you can use only serialized classes. Or you are trying to access some class which is declared outside of filter function and that class is not serializable.

Comment: I know, and that class was the one that created half of the rdd I am trying to apply filter on. Question is, what kind of transformations can I do to the rdd to not have this happen anymore?